How to Trace Ignite WriteBehindCache DataSource Metrics
We have using Ignite as Embedded Server node in Spring Boot Application for Writing data to the Database RDBMS. The Database being oracle in our case
For Every Request for our Microservice [ Spring boot app]
We have 4 to 5 caches Operation t only for 3 caches, Insert & update in 2 Caches which goes to the Database as per WRITEBEHIND =true and WRITETHROUGH=true Property.

Issue Area
During Load Testing we find each of request is taking 3 seconds, hangs in either of the caches one or other

DataSources are also configured to use Hikariconnection pool



How do we find why it is taking time in Put/Get in Ignite? Is there any Way to find how much time DB Connection has taken, How much time actual Insert Query has taken by Ignite

Details
We are using 8 Core 32 GB RAM [ OffHeap Default] , No DataRegion Configuration Done
No Errors were seen in Logs of Ignite Embedded


Sample Configuration
<property name="readThrough" value="true" />
<property name="writeThrough" value="true" /> 
<property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true"/>
<property name="writeBehindFlushThreadCount" value="8" />

**Datasource configuration**
    <bean id="dataSourceUY" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@db.oracle.com:1531/TEST" />
        <property name="username" value="myapp" />
        <property name="password" value="db_pwd" />
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="50" />
        <property name="minimumIdle" value="10" />
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="20000" />
<property name="connectionTimeout" value="30000"/>
<property name="poolName" value="dataSourceUY"/>
<property name="maxLifetime" value="180000"/>
    </bean>

<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">

     <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>
</bean>
    </property>
            </bean>
        </property> 
        <!--<property name="executorConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ExecutorConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="orchPool"/>
                    <property name="size" value="10"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property> -->
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="ImportedCluster" />
        <property name="systemThreadPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="stripedPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="clientMode" value="false" />
        <property name="workDirectory"  value="/ignite/workdir/orch" />
         <property name="discoverySpi">
        
            <bean
                class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean
                        class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <value>myapp-services:47500..47520</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property> 
        

How to find where it is taking time , DB Connection or DB Insert in Write Behind
required Optimization Configuration   Ignite
Please find the Breakup during the Test, Each Row is Request from Jmeter , each of them stuck in one or other cache eventually taking 3 seconds Response time
Is there any Observability to trace internals of the Ignite

